# Translating int into char using LWJGL's Keyboard class?

Tags: java, opengl, keyboard, lwjgl

So I was wondering, when using LWJGL's Keyboard class, is there a method to get a character from an int? I was thinking about something like this:

```
    char keyF = Keyboard.getChar(Keyboard.KEY_F);
```

would return `f`.

Is there such a method? And if so, what is it called?

**NOTE I have already tried casting from int to char**

Comment: Parse the `Keyboard.getKeyName(keyCode)` which is a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way (I think) to get it other than creating a method yourself for the keys you use. For example if you only use X and Y keys, your method would look like this.

```
public char getChar(int code){
    switch (code){
        case Keyboard.KEY_X: return 'x';
        case Keyboard.KEY_Y: return 'y';
    }
}
```

But you have to create a case for each key you use.

Also see http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html#getKeyName%28int%29
It says how to convert a int to String. You could probably use the first character of that string. Note that this would not work for keys like SHIFT, F1 etc.,

Comment: Yeah, the method you're referring to is (as Joob Eggen said) `Keyboard.getKeyName(keyCode)`. Thank you!